How can I solve Flutter Problem in release mode run?
When Run my flutter app with Released mode. App Run on my emulator but give me error after running application. But Why give this error i don't understand now. Please help me to identify the issue like what happening

I am using Java JDK : 17
also select Android Studio project structure to JDK path from my local computer path.
I also adding screenshot of the error.
Please help me to find out the exact problem.

Try flutter pub upgrade to upgrade the package is the most recommended approach.

not working after executing this command @Harsh bangari vaiya


java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Looks like there is an incompatibility issue between your Java code and the Java Runtime Environment (JRE).
Use Android Studio to configure your Flutter project to use an older Java version.
Open project in Android Studio.

Go to File > Project Structure.
In the left pane, select SDK Location. Uncheck the box for "Use
embedded JDK (recommended)".
In the JDK Location field, enter the absolute path to the older Java
installation directory (e.g., /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk).


Still not working . give me error

Share your flutter doctor details.
